# Dividir cadena con metodo Split()

Tags: c#, linq, split

**Json de Distritos**

```
[
  {
    "codigo": "1-1",
    "ubicacion": "nombre"
  },
  {
    "codigo": "1-2",
    "ubicacion": "nombre"
  },
  {
    "codigo": "1-3",
    "ubicacion": "nombre"
  },
  {
    "codigo": "1-4",
    "ubicacion": "nombre"
  },
]
```

**Si codigoProvincia es = "1"**

```
 distritos.Where(x => x.codigo.Split("-")[0] == codigoProvincia).ToList();
```

Me va a buscar todos los distritos que en su código tengan **"1-"** o sea todos los que están en el `json` de arriba ya que el guion es el carácter delimitador esto funciona perfecto.

***Json de Corregimientos***

```
[
  {
    "codigo": "1-1-1",
    "ubicacion": "nombre"
  },
  {
    "codigo": "1-1-2",
    "ubicacion": "nombre"
  },
  {
    "codigo": "1-1-3",
    "ubicacion": "nombre"
  },
  {
    "codigo": "1-1-4",
    "ubicacion": "nombre"
  }
]
```

Como escogí de provincia el código **1** los distritos tendrá el código **1-1** o sea que en el código de abajo `codigoDistrito` será **1-1**.

Intento hacer con el mismo código:

```
   ... corregimientos.Where(x => x.codigo.Split("-")[0] == codigoDistrito).ToList();
```

Me tendría que retornar todos los corregimientos que en su código tengan "1-1" o sea los del `json` de arriba pero no logro encontrar la lógica para hacerlo.

Creo que tiene que ver con el carácter delimitador pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo.

Es lo mismo pero lo que cambia es la cadena que se va a evaluar para traer el resultado ya que los códigos de distritos son por ejemplo **1-1** mientras que los corregimientos son **1-1-1**.

Comment: Prueba con `corregimientos.Where(x => x.codigo.StartsWith(codigoDistrito)).ToList();`

Comment: Ah caray y antes había visto ese método pero no lo recordaba, si me funciono me trajo los corregimiento, gracias @Cris223511.dev

Comment: Añadí una respuesta donde te doy una breve explicación, saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías usar el método `StartsWith()` para que obtengas todos los corregimientos que comiencen con el código del distrito (tu variable `codigoDistrito`), sería algo como esto:

```
corregimientos.Where(x => x.codigo.StartsWith(codigoDistrito)).ToList();
```